# Netlogo: Raster not loading in the world

Tags: gis, netlogo

i just have some lines of code to try and import a raster I have but its not working

```
extensions [ gis ]

globals[datos-mundo]

to setup-mapa
 
  set datos-mundo gis:load-dataset "D:/Geografico/fdsa.asc"
  
end
```

I dont know why its not working but im not getting an error, just that the world stays black, any advice will be welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could export your map as an image (PNG) and then open it using import-pcolors. I find this much more straightforward than the GIS extension. I have a video tutorial of this here.

https://youtu.be/VzvgBzO7ls0